# Vue waiting for data from props before using

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

I keep running into an issue where I am awaiting data from a prop to do something within it inside my created hook. It keeps throwing errors such as "this.value is not defined" (As it has not yet loaded from prop)

I have fixed some of these issues using `v-if` and only using as needed. However in some cases I wanted to use that prop info within my created and when that happens, I end up getting errors and am not sure how to best tell that part of the created to "wait" for the data before running.

Any advice?

--

*Update to add some example code.*

On the App.js page, I am calling in the "userInfo" and setting it in data like so. I am doing this for two reasons. First to check if user is logged in, and secondly taking the time to save the users info as it will be used later on throughout the app. (Please note, user and userInfo are different and contain different info. User is email/password whilst userInfo is username, bio, etc.)

```
data() {
  return {
    user: null,
    userInfo: null,
  }
},
created(){
//let user = firebase.auth().currentUser
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if(user){
      this.user = user
      let ref = db.collection('users')
      .where('user_id', '==', this.user.uid)
      ref.get().then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        this.userInfo = doc.data()
      })
    })

    } else {
      this.user = null
    }
  })
},
```

Now, I pass this information down within the  using v-bind. and then call it in areas I need some info using props.

The issue comes when I want to do something such as -

```
if(this.userInfo) {
  value = true  
}
```

Calling this.userInfo throws an error "this.userInfo is null" (I set it to null in the data() of the page as default).

Comment: Have you tried to use the variables in `mounted` instead of `created` ?

Comment: You might share an example of your code. However, you're describing a state where the passed in prop doesn't even exist yet like a promise response. Might that be the reason?

Comment: @Aer0 possibly, although I am passing props from App.vue down to a page. It does load in and is usable within methods, but is not ready right away as the document loads (or even when mounted, it seems)

Comment: @Jesper I just gave that a go and it still seems it is grabbing it too soon?

Comment: @KJParkerI'd assume you share some code with us. Might be easier to track down the problem. However, I still assume it's a promise/async issue. The promise my be resolved while using in a method but not at the beginning (created hook).

Comment: Yup sorry @Aer0 just took a bit of formatting as it was a mess :) Updated my question to contain examples

Comment: @KJParker How about [`immediate`-ly `watch`-ing](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you're running into a Promise resolving issue. When passing a result as a Prop which gets resolved by a Promise, that result will basically be empty which eventually will lead to an error in your Child Components `created()` hook.

I would recommend using `v-if` as you've already done in the Child Component itself. However, I'd use the `v-if` in the Parent Component to simply show/hide the Child. That should not only resolve the problem within your `created()` hook, but also help building up a more readable markup in your Child Component where you could just remove all `v-if`s.

So let's assume you have a Parent/Child relationship like that.

```
<SomeParentComponent>
  <SomeChildComponent :someProp="yourProp" />
</SomeParentComponent>
```

When `yourProp` is set after a resolving Promise, the initial value will be `null`, `undefined`, or whatever you've set it to. To avoid passing in an empty prop you can just wrap the in a `v-if` which's expression evaluates to `yourProp` just like so.

```
<SomeParentComponent>
  <SomeChildComponent :someProp="yourProp" v-if="yourProp" />
</SomeParentComponent>                           <!-- ^-- See here -->
```

Doing so, the Child will only be rendered when `yourProp` is set and therefore you won't get any errors anymore.

Comment: Ah ok great! Thank you @Aer0 that works perfectly! What sort of impact does this have on the load-speed. I guess it depends on how long it takes to grab that initial data/update child?

Also, is there a better way to avoid this in the future?

Comment: You are suggesting the use of a `v-if` direction, which will create a jumping behaviour, when the asynchronous data is available for components below.

Comment: That's correct. If you'd pass in a Promise as a Prop you could wait for the Promise to resolve in an `async` manner. Also, having a jumpy behavior is something you should take care about differently. If you've data that rely on your Prop to get displayed properly, you'd also get a jumpy behavior even with a default value.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer provides a great solution, which set `v-if` on entire Child component in Parent component. However there's still some edge cases where your prop literally becomes empty or null if the API returns so, which eventually ends up never rendering your Child component at all though you might need to show some default texts/styles, or maybe you're working on some projects that you don't have control over the parent component. In those cases, you could internally handle this problem just fine by checking if the prop has already available in the created hook, if not, you should dynamically watch this prop until it becomes available.

```
// your component
export default {
  props: ['userInfo'],

  created() {
    // check if the prop userInfo available or not
    if (this.userInfo) {
      // do your thing
    } else {
      // start watching this prop
      const unwatch = this.$watch('userInfo', () => {
        // do your thing when userInfo is available

        // tear down this watcher as you now no longer need it
        unwatch()
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Props should be available in the `created` hook. Assuming the values are synchronous. Try to add `default` values, in order to remove unnecessary `v-if` directives. This should solve the issue for both synchronous and asynchronous data.

```
{
  props: {
    length: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: What if a prop is `Promise`? I think that's the problem here.

Comment: I just edited my answer. In that case, they are certainly not immediately available.

Comment: Even though it helps and should be best practice setting a default value it's still not the answer to the question. If you rely on a value to be set properly during `created()` hook you have to make sure it's either set up during Component creation or use another way of relying on your Pop.

Comment: @Aer0 that is not right. You could have a specific behaviour in case, the data is not there. Also what you are saying is certainly no best practise.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two approaches I can think of:

### 1. Dependency injection

The parent/root to `provide` the data/object down the component tree and the receiving end (children) to `inject` them.

**Parent**

```js
{
  data: () => ({
    userInfo: null
  }),

  created() {
    // Populates data via Firebase 
    // Code omitted for brevity...

    this.userInfo = doc.data();
  },

  provide() {
    return Object.defineProperty({}, 'userInfo', {
      get: () => this.userInfo
    })
  }
}
```

**Children**

```js
// Children
{
  inject: ['userInfo'],

  created() {
    if (this.userInfo) {
      // Do something 
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if (this.userInfo) {
      // Do something 
    }
  },
  // Any lifecycle hooks, methods or virtually anywhere needing a reference to this object
}
```

### 2. Vuex store

Rather than passing props and having to deal with possible asynchrony issues; you could let Vuex take care of synchronizing the states for you and stop worrying about the data being `null` or `undefined`.

**Store**

```js
export default {
  state: {
    userInfo: null
  },
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_USER(state, payload) {
      state.userInfo = payload;
    }
  }
}
```

**Parent/App.js**

```js
export default {
  created() {
    // On firebase success callback
    this.$store.commit('UPDATE_USER', doc.data());
  }
}
```

**Children**

```js
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'userInfo'
    ])
  },

  created() { },
  mounted() { },
  methods() { 
    if (this.userInfo) {
      // Do something safely
    }
  },
  // Anywhere
}
```